# WinJs-Data Binding with a custom arrayList

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

It seem to me so complicated and i have tried  many of things but with no result.
I want to create a Horizontal List View on my Metro application (Winjs/HTML), so create the template and the listView html element .
The Problem that the DataSource from where i will get my image_url is advanced .
This is the form of this DataSource returned from my Json web Service (I don't know if it is a HashTable, ListArray...?? ):

```
"path_categories":
{
"star":"the image url ",
"Fruits ": " the image url ",
"Animaux":"the image url ",
"Country":"the image url ",
"Coulor":"the image url ",
"Town":"the image url ",
"capital":"the image url "
}
```

I sould set the specific attribute to bind with my 

enter code here

Any help will appreciated , Thinks

Comment: Are you attempting to bind the above JSON data to the listView in the JavaScript Grid app template that comes with Visual Studio? That template uses JSON data defined in the data.js file to demonstrate databinding without the added complexity of returning JSON from an external service, so it can show you how to wire up the ListView to a WinJS.Binding.list based on your data. Keep in mind, though, that each "item" in your data should use a consistent name for the property that contains the value, which doesn't seem to be the case above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your view model need to use the data coming in and exposes items something like this.

```
var ViewModel = WinJS.Class.define(
    function ViewModel(data)
    {
        var categories = data.path_categories;
        var keys = object.keys(categories);
        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            var imageUrl = categories[key];
            var item = { imageUrl : imageUrl };
            items.push(item);
        }

        this.items = new WinJS.Binding.List(items);
    });

function ondataload(data)
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
    listView.winControl.itemDataSource = viewModel.items.dataSource;
}
```

HTH.